# Do Kubernetes persistent volume claims bind again if the persistent volume is being deleted and recreated?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have the following `pvc` (Persistent Volume Claim):

```
piVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-claim-web
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

and the Google Cloud-backed `pv` (Persistent Volume):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: test-1
    fsType: ext4
```

and the Disk in Google cloud that exists.

If I create first the `pv` and after the `pvc`, `kubectl get pvc,pv` will show:

```
NAME                                STATUS                                VOLUME            CAPACITY     ACCESSMODES              AGE
test-claim-web                      Bound                                 test-pv-1         10Gi         RWO                      15s
NAME                                CAPACITY                              ACCESSMODES       STATUS       CLAIM                    REASON    AGE
test-pv-1                           10Gi                                  RWO               Bound        default/test-claim-web             25s
```

But if I delete and recreate the `pv`, `kubectl get pvc,pv` will show:

```
NAME                                STATUS                                VOLUME            CAPACITY     ACCESSMODES              AGE
test-claim-web                      Bound                                 test-pv-1         10Gi         RWO                      3m
NAME                                CAPACITY                              ACCESSMODES       STATUS       CLAIM                    REASON    AGE
test-pv-1                           10Gi                                  RWO               Available                                       18s
```

- Why is the `pvc` still `Bound`?
- Doesn't the `pvc` (re-)bind automatically? (I also observed that creating the `pv` after the `pvc` makes the `pvc` wait forever with `Pending` status.)

I use the following Kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: Are you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> if I delete and recreate the pv, kubectl get pvc,pv will show [bound].
>   Why is the pvc still Bound?

That's bug in Kubernetes 1.2, it will be fixed in 1.3. Both PV and PVC should get Bound eventually.

However, deleting a bound PV is very bad idea, as the PVC may be used in a running pod and the pod suddenly looses storage underneath. You should never touch bound PVs!

> I also observed that creating the pv after the pvc makes the pvc wait forever with Pending status

It won't wait forever, it should get bound after 10 minutes. Use `kube-controller-manager --pvclaimbinder-sync-period=15s` to shorten it to 15 seconds. Again, this will be better in Kubernetes 1.3, 15 seconds will be default there.